# I live a period in one country and a period in another; what do I do with both local websites?

Tags: seo, local-seo, email-address, name, phone-number

I live in country X for 6 months and in country Y for 6 months.
I have a local website for country X and a local website for country Y.

Both websites have local phone numbers; so if people visiting them can't get me, they'd probably bounce out to search a competitor,
which raises the chance that the site they visited will have SEO damage.

How could I prevent such SEO damage?

Comment: Can't you just update the phone number on the site to one where you could be reached when you aren't local?   Then change it back when you are local.

Comment: I'm just saying that when you are out of the country, that might be a gamble worth taking.  You could always change it back when you are in town.

Comment: you can ask people to add you in Whatsapp for country X. Whatsapp doesn't need any SIM Card. Your number works wherever you go. You can give your latest number, social media contact, email id or provide a contact form so people can reach you out.

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., the phone/cell companies offer a feature referred to as "Call Forwarding". When you leave one location, you set the phone there to forward any incoming calls to your number at the other location. And visa-versa. You would need to consider the possible costs of long-distance charges, however, the potential earnings from sales of those not-missed calls might be sufficient to offset the expense.

Another option would be providing one business number, a cell phone (seperate from your personal cell phone). As long as you were able to get a reliable connection in both areas and there weren't any "roaming" or otherwise excessive fees involved. That would eliminate even the annoyance of changing things back and forth based on your local.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions that can address this issue.

> Have your updated phone number on both websites based on the country you are living in.

This will help your customers understand to reach out to you on your alternate phone number, when the first one they dial/text does not work. (But if the international charges are high, giving option such as Whatsapp Text/Call would work. Could use 'Whatsapp for Business' as well to address customer queries at one place.)

> Push out a store wide notification on your local website about the contact number to reach out to you while you're in another country

This will help your customers understand that they have to text/call to reach you on the notified number. (Do not use popups as they are annoying for the users)